# yaml-mode empties whitespace lines

Tags: formatting, pretty-print

Our project has a large yaml file edited by multiple developers in multiple environments. When I edit the file in emacs, yaml-mode (I assume?) will trim any whitespace lines:

```
         Value:
           Item: foo
           Count: 10
---------
   Selection:
     All:
     - Item: Name
```

The hyphens above represent the legal spaces that yaml-mode deletes on save.

I have no strong opinions on the "correct" whitespace here but since my editor is in the minority in the team, I'd like it to be consistent and leave those spaces.

How can I ask or hack yaml mode to do this?

Comment: Look into `before-save-hooks`, not sure it's `yaml-mode`. More likely your other global settings.

Comment: Try it without your init.el or .emacs. Maybe you have global-whitespace-cleanup-mode activated?

Comment: @wvxvw ah yeah it's prelude-cleanup-maybe in my before-save-hooks. I can disable that with prelude-clean-whitespace-on-save, once I figure out how to do a mode-local variable...

Answer (score 2):

With help from @wvxvw, the problem wasn't yaml-mode, but my before-save-hooks. That listed prelude-cleanup-maybe as the only entry. Disabling prelude-clean-whitespace-on-save fixed the problem. With help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565759/set-variable-under-specific-mode-emacs), the code below makes that change every time I open a yaml file:

```
;; whitespace cleanup can conflict with other people's IDEs, so don't do it
(add-hook 'yaml-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (make-variable-buffer-local 'prelude-clean-whitespace-on-save)
            (setq prelude-clean-whitespace-on-save nil)))
```